# Set image and hover image to <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" .../asp>

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, commandfield

i have this

```
  <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" CancelImageUrl="~/img/annulla_grigio.png" EditImageUrl="~/img/modifica_grigio.png"
                                        ShowEditButton="True" UpdateText="" UpdateImageUrl="~/img/salva_grigio.png" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"
                                        ItemStyle-CssClass="tabella_p_modifica" ControlStyle-CssClass="modifica_hover" EditText=""/>
```

And it works when i hover on it change with other image, for example change gray pencil into red pencil. But when i click on Edit button it's show two buttons as Update and Cancel. But with same image of edit.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to try is to switch `ButtonType="Button"` to `ButtonType="Image"`. The reason is that your `ImageUrl` properties won't appear unless you set that to *Image*

I suspect you are setting the *pencil* image inside of your CSS class `modifica_hover`. This class will apply to both the *Edit* and *Cancel* buttons. That's probably why you see the pencil for both of them.

An alternative that you may want to try is to create this field as a `TemplateField` which gives you more control. Just make sure to pass the correct `CommandName` for the event to trigger the `GridView` event.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/img/modifica_grigio.png" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="~/img/salva_grigio.png" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/img/annulla_grigio.png" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thanks Kirk. Sorry for late answering you but i was very busy. Happy new year in late to all!  I removed the tag " ImageUrl " and I used a CssClass and also because I had to use the Button gave me trouble seeing .
Anyway thanks again !